# What is the difference between CTRL-T and CTRL-O in Vim?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

The documentation isn't especially clear—<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is to jump back in the tag stack, whereas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is to jump back to the previous cursor position. What's the difference between <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>? They both appear to exhibit the same behavior.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> is working with [tag stack](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> is working with [jumplist](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Jumping_to_previously_visited_locations)

Tag stack and jumplist are different list in vim, but they might have same items when you jumping through tags (eg. using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>)